# Is there a function for multiple column UNPIVOT without a matching WHERE clause in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a dataset that looks similar to below:

| ID Key | Indicator 1 | Indicator 1 Value | Indicator 2 | Indicator 2 | Indicator 3 | Indicator 3 Value | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID### | Apples | TRUE | Pears | FALSE | Oranges | null | etc... |
| ID### | Oranges | TRUE | Pears | FALSE | APPLES | null | etc... |
| ID### | PEARS | TRUE | APPLES | FALSE | ORANGES | null | etc... |

I've been able to unpivot the indicator names successfully into a single column however my difficulty is matching the indicator Value appropriately to the Indicator Name. Is there a WHERE statement that allows me to grep between the column names to unpivot or a similar operation that can help me sort this? The dataset in question comes from a XML set which may explain the abnormalities.

Comment: Which DBMS? Microsoft SQL Server, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server I'd just use `APPLY`

```
SELECT
  your_table.id_key,
  exploded.indicator,
  exploded.val
FROM
  your_table
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES
    (indicator_1, indicator_1_value),
    (indicator_2, indicator_2_value),
    ...
    (indicator_n, indicator_n_value)
)
  AS exploded(indicator, val)
WHERE
  exploded.indicator IS NOT NULL
```

Other DBMSs have similar functionality, such as lateral joins.